# Loading multiple textures from different url's fails

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render textures on planes loaded from different URL's. For some reason after 2nd or 3rd image I can see in browser that loading image is stuck and it is not being rendered.[image]

Adding the code used:

```
function init() {
   loadPicturesFromDirectUrl();
}

function loadPicturesFromDirectUrl(currentPictureIndex) {
    if (currentPictureIndex === undefined) {
        currentPictureIndex = 0;
    }
    var picture = data.pictures[currentPictureIndex];
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load(picture.url, function (texture) {
        renderPicture(picture, texture);
        currentPictureIndex++;
        if (currentPictureIndex > data.pictures.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        loadPicturesFromDirectUrl(currentPictureIndex);
    }, null, function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

function renderPicture(picture, texture) {
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(picture.size.width, picture.size.height);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    var planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    planeMesh.position.x = picture.location.x;
    planeMesh.position.y = picture.location.y;
    planeMesh.rotateY(myzeum.toRadians(180));
    scene.add(planeMesh);
}
```

Comment: Are you loading all images over `HTTPS`? Maybe it's not working because you load insecure content (via `HTTP`).

Comment: You've got to give us something to work with. Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I added the code to original post.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to preload all the pictures in one function and store them in an array and render them only after all of them have been loaded. Like so:

```
var all_textures = [];
function init() {
    loadPicturesFromDirectUrl();
    for int (i = 0; i < all_picture.length; i++) {
        renderPicture(data.pictures[i], all_textures[i])
    }
}
function loadPicturesFromDirectUrl(currentPictureIndex) {
    if (currentPictureIndex === undefined) {
        currentPictureIndex = 0;
    }
    var picture = data.pictures[currentPictureIndex];
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load(picture.url, function (texture) {
        all_textures[currentPictureIndex] = texture
        currentPictureIndex++;
        if (currentPictureIndex > data.pictures.length - 1) {
            return;
        }
        loadPicturesFromDirectUrl(currentPictureIndex);
    }, null, function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

function renderPicture(picture, texture) {
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(picture.size.width, picture.size.height);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
    var planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    planeMesh.position.x = picture.location.x;
    planeMesh.position.y = picture.location.y;
    planeMesh.rotateY(myzeum.toRadians(180));
    scene.add(planeMesh);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but even without the rendering, the loading sometimes fails. It goes to onError but there is no details about the error.

Comment: I think you might also want to try it with the loading manager https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager
This way you can guarantee the pictures are being loaded synchronously. Are any particular pictures throwing 404s or 500s?

Comment: Actually non of them. When loading 10 images for example, 2 being loaded, and second one is returning 200 but as you can see in original post, only few rows of pixels are being loaded. I think it is something internal in three js lib